# How to refer C++ enum in Powershell script

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, scripting

Am new to powershell scripting. Can anybody suggest simple way to refer a enum/constant defined in C++ header file in powershell? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an example about enum/constant you have defined and how you would use it in Powershell?

Comment: The following link may provide what you are looking for.  It depends on whether you mean that the C++ header has been compiled into a type that PowerShell knows about (i.e., a .Net type).  If so, this link could help: http://kristofmattei.be/2013/04/23/when-using-an-enum-in-powershell-use-the-members-name-not-the-members-value/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to do that like you could with a .NET enum.  You will either have to:

- Parse the header file and find the value yourself.
- Synthesize a C++/CLI cpp file that does a #include of the header file and exposes the
  enum/const via a .NET type.

For the first, you can use Get-Content to read in the header file line-by-line and -match and/or Select-String to do a regular expression search.  For the second, (the route I would go), you will need to use cl.exe with the `/clr` switch to generate a DLL that can then be loaded with `Add-Type -Path C:\clicpp.dll`.  Once you've declared a managed enum in C++/CLI, which uses the values from the header file, you can reference it in PowerShell like so:

```
[NamespaceName.EnumName]::EnumValue
```